# retriving a text file content information in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file which includes 300 lines. For example the first line is:

```
ANSWER: correct: yes, time: 6.880674, guess: Lay, action: Lay, file: 16
```

or the second line is:

```
ANSWER: correct: no, time: 7.150422, guess: Put on top, action: Stir, file: 18
```

Only 'time' and 'file' values are numbers and the others are string.

I want to store the values of "correct", "time", "guess", "action" and "file" of the whole 300 lines in the different variables (like some arrays).

How can I do this in the Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1:

You can use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) with the following [formatSpec](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btghhyz-1-formatSpec):

```
formatSpec = 'ANSWER: correct:%s time:%f guess:%s action:%s file: %f';
data = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,'Delimiter',',');
```

where `fileID` is the file identifier obtained by [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html?s_tid=doc_ta).

### Option 2:

Another option is to use [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), with the formatting above (directly with the file name, no fileID):

```
data = readtable('53485991.txt','Format',formatSpec,'Delimiter',',',...
    'ReadVariableNames',false);
% the next lines are just to give the table variables some meaningful names:
varNames = strsplit(fmt,{'ANSWER',':','%s',' ','%f'});
data.Properties.VariableNames = varNames(2:end-1);
```

**The result** (ignore the values, as I messed that example a little bit while playing with it):

```
data =
  4×5 table
    correct     time          guess         action    file
    _______    ______    _______________    ______    ____
    'yes'      6.8888    'Lay'              'Lay'      16 
    'no'       7.8762    'Put on top'       'Stir'     18 
    'no'       7.1503    'Put on bottom'    'Stir'      3 
    'no'        7.151    'go'               'Stir'    270
```

The advantage in option 2 is that a table is [a much more convenient way](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/advantages-of-using-tables.html) to hold these data than a cell array (which is the output of `textscan`).

Comment: Learned something new. The `textscan` is elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I use "option 1", data will be appeared in such a form: data = 

    {1x1 cell}    [6.8807]    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    [0x1 double], but how can I retrive my information like time,correct,etc from this data?

Comment: _First_, it's better to use option 2. _Second_, you should type: `correct = data{1}`, `time = data{2}` and so on until 5 (file), for each field in your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and suggestion :)

Comment: option 2 yields to this error. Error Caused by:
    Reading failed at line 1.  A field on that line may have contained the wrong type of value.

Comment: You have to check that your data is formatted correctly, exactly as you wrote it above. Another option is of encoding issue, but it's hard to tell from the info in this error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgetl` to get a line of the file and `while` loop to read all of the lines.

For each line, use `regexp` to partition the string into cells by `:` and `,` delimiter. Then, use `strip` to remove leading and trailing whitespace for each cell.

Here is the solution:

```
f = fopen('a.txt');

aline = fgetl(f);
i = 1;
while ischar(aline)
    content = strip(regexp(aline,':|,','split'));
    correct{i} = content{3};
    time(i) = str2double(content{5});
    guess{i}= content{7};
    action{i} = content{9};
    file(i) = str2double(content{11});
    i = i + 1;
    aline = fgetl(f);
end

fclose(f);
```

Example:

Suppose a.txt file looks like this

```
ANSWER: correct: yes, time: 6.880674, guess: Lay, action: Lay, file: 16
ANSWER: correct: no, time: 7.150422, guess: Put on top, action: Stir, file: 18
```

After executing the script, the results are

```
correct =
  1×2 cell array
    'yes'    'no'

time =
    6.8807    7.1504

guess =
  1×2 cell array
    'Lay'    'Put on top'

action =
  1×2 cell array
    'Lay'    'Stir'

file =
    16    18
```