# Fast splitting string

Tags: matlab, performance, time, strsplit, regexp-substr

I have a series of lines that I read from a file (over 2700) of this type:

```
A = '1; 23245675; -234567; 123456; ...; 0'
```

`A` is a string with `;` as the delimiter for data.

To split the string I used the `strsplit` function first, but it was too slow to execute. Then I used `regexp` like this:

```
regexp(A,';','split')
```

Is there an even faster function than `regexp`?

Comment: I don't get it, in your example `A` is a string or a cell array? And if it is a cell array, what are the strings you split? Those within `A` does not contain `;` at all. BTW, if your data is structured, consider `readtable` or `dlmread` as faster options to read it in a formatted way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53486754/2627163).

Comment: A is a string. I have to split a string in more efficent way if it is possible.

Comment: Have you considered `textscan`? [it is way faster than all the options you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534356/2627163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a builtin function<sup>1</sup>, [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) is probably the fastest option:

```
result = textscan(A{1},'%f','Delimiter',';');
```

Here is a little benchmark to show that:

```
A = repmat('1; 23245675; -234567; 123456; 0',1,100000); % a long string
regexp_time = timeit(@ () regexp(A,';','split'))
strsplit_time = timeit(@ () strsplit(A,';'))
split_time = timeit(@ () split(A,';'))
textscan_time = timeit(@ () textscan(A,'%f','Delimiter',';'))
```

the result:

```
regexp_time =
      0.33054
strsplit_time =
      0.45939
split_time =
      0.24722
textscan_time =
     0.057712
```

`textscan` is the fastest, and is **~4.3 times** faster than the next method (`split`).

It is the fastest option no matter what is the length of the string to split (Note the log scale of the x-axis):

[image: benchmark of string splitting]

---

<sup>1</sup>"A built-in function is part of the MATLAB executable. MATLAB does not implement these functions in the MATLAB language. Although most built-in functions have a .m file associated with them, this file only supplies documentation for the function." (from the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

The possible split function I can think about are `regexp`, `strsplit`, and `split`.

I compared the performance of them for a large string. The result shows `split` is slightly faster while `strsplit` is around 2 times slower than `regexp`.

Here is how I compared them:

First, create a large string A (around 16 million data) according to your question.

```
A = '1; 23245675; -234567; 123456; 0';
for ii=1:22
    A = strcat(A,A);
end
```

**Option 1: `regexp`**

```
tic
regexp(A,';','split');
toc

Elapsed time is 12.548295 seconds.
```

**Option 2: `strsplit`**

```
tic
strsplit(A,';');
toc

Elapsed time is 23.347392 seconds.
```

**Option 3: `split`**

```
tic
split(A,';');
toc

Elapsed time is 9.678433 seconds.
```

So `split` might help you speed up a little bit but it is not obvious.